# Larger attack surface?

Tags: attacks

My company had a plain Cisco router connected to Comcast - NAT'd (Scenario 1) and now we have an MSP solution connected to the same Comcast connection (Scenario 2).

I need someone with more expertise than I to state/guess which one has the larger attack surface and WHY? (based on this limited nmap scan before/after data - it's all I could get on short notice).

In Scenario 1, the PPTP went to our IP phone system, no VPNs, etc. on the Cisco, only NAT.

Scenario 1

web-based nmap port scan "Frequently Used Ports":

```
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT      STATE   SERVICE
1723/tcp  open    pptp
Nmap done: IP address (1 host up) scanned in 20.65 seconds
```

Scenario 2
web-based nmap port scan "Frequently Used Ports":

```
Not shown: 995 closed ports, 4 filtered ports
PORT      STATE   SERVICE
444/tcp   open    snpp
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 16.19 seconds
```

And if I bang on port 444 from outside, I get this:
[image]

Comment: more ports are exposed to the internet in scenario 2 (5 ports) - that's your larger surface (granted, some inference going on there)

Comment: You definitely don't want to be exposing your sonicwall management interface to the public.